# Thymeleaf- When clicking in an anchor tag, display model object in a div

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my controller I return a model object like this:

```
double[] calculateYearMonth=statistics.CalculateActive();
modelAndView.addObject("statistics",calculateYearMonth);
```

This calculateActive method returns an array with 4 members.
Female, Male, Year, Month, Ratio.

In my Html I have a div and underneath it I have two links:

```html
<div class="row centerAlign">
    <h1><strong>RESULTS</strong></h1>
</div>

<div class="row centerAlign" id="month">
    <div>
        <a href="" style="float: right;">Month</a>
        <a href="" style="float: left;">Year</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the anchor that says Month, I want to get the object statistics[3] - so the third member and display it where it says RESULTS.
And when I click on Year, I want to get statistics but 4th member. And display it on the Results.

How do I do that using Thyemeleaf? How do I link the selected anchor with that to be displayed? 
Thanks

Comment: Using Javascript?

Comment: How ? Cuz th:utext={{$statistics}} to get the statistics object and then I dont know how to change it depending on the clicked anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to store the data in a javascript object:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var stats = /*[[${statistics}]]*/{};
</script>
```

Then this javascript object `stats` is available on the client side and you can fetch data required based on the anchor clicked

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="float: right;" 
   class="results" data-index="3">Month</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);"style="float: right;" 
   class="results" data-index="4">Year</a>
```

And in the event handler you can write:

```
$(".results").on('click', function(){
  var index = $(this).data("index");
  var statObj = stats[index];
});
```